# Entering insert mode automatically when editing git commit messages

Tags: git, vim

If I do a `git commit`, when Vim opens, I want to be in insert mode straight away.

I noticed that the `filetype` is set to `gitcommit` when editing, so I thought I could achieve this with an autocommand.

```
au BufRead gitcommit startinsert!
```

This doesn't work though, what am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

I settled on `au FileType gitcommit execute "normal! O" | startinsert` to add a new line above the current and then enter insert mode ready for entering a message.

Comment: Your proposed solution is not so nice for messages which already contain text like --amend or merges. Do you know how to change the behaviour for those situations?

Comment: No, I've found the same thing and would like to know a better way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `:au Event pattern command`, the pattern is usually matched against the buffer name.  Instead of `BufRead gitcommit`, you could use `BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG`.  If you want to match against the filetype option, then use the `FileType` event.

I tend to write multi-line commit messages, and I have an autocommand (from vimrc_example.vim) that does

```
exe "normal! g`\""
```

whenever I enter a new buffer, so how about

```
au FileType gitcommit 1 | startinsert
```

to go to the first line before entering Insert mode?  Now that I have tested it, I think I will keep it. :)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to debug autocommands? I did `:set ft?` to find out the filetype of the current buffer and I have other autocommands which such as `au BufReadPost quickfix setlocal nospell` which use the same thing.

I've settled for `au FileType gitcommit execute "normal! O" | startinsert` to add a new line above and then enter insert mode. Thank you :)

Comment: First of all, `:execute "normal! 0"` does not add a new line.  It just moves the cursor to the start of the line.  My `:1` moves to the first line.  You can use `:verbose au BufReadPost quickfix` to see what autocommands are defined for that event and pattern, and which file defines them.  Similarly, `:verbose set ft?`.

Comment: It would do if that was a zero, but it's not, it's a capital o (O) ;) Thanks for the tip on `:verbose`, I will look into that.

Answer (score 13):

An alternate approach:

```
export GIT_EDITOR='vim +startinsert'
```

or add `!` in the end to start from the end of message (useful, when using git hooks for message completion)

```
export GIT_EDITOR='vim +startinsert!'
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I considered this before I posted the question, but I thought I'd like to automate some more but I left that out of the question for clarity. You can also do `vim +start` btw.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit more complex than it needs to be, but you can do this with an individual filetype plugin:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/ftplugin/gitcommit
$ echo 'startinsert!' > !$/git-commit-insert.vim
```

Comment: Thanks, I will bear this in mind in the future, but I already have a few autocommands and I'd like to do this in a similar way :)