# How to start typing when entering VIM during git rebase?

Tags: git, powershell, vim, rebase

While using Powershell 5, when I type `git rebase -i <sha>` vim fires up and I get the a list of commits on their pick lines.

Moving the caret to the start of any of those lines and changing pick to `squash`, `s`, `fixup`, `f` etc appears to be blocked initially. It would appear that the cursor keys should be hit randomly, random characters entered and eventually vim lets text be entered as I intend.

What is vim doing here and is it simply an option?
How do you stop it?

[EDIT] I realise that the initial mode of vim may not be the mode I'm looking for, however I'm not sure how to check that, change it or anything related. If the initial mode of vim, as entered when typing `git rebase...` does need changing, a good answer to this question would be how to change that mode once vim has started up.

Comment: You could figure out how to configure git to use another editor.

Comment: Yes; I could figure out how to use another editor, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Assuming no ranting: Are you asking how to use Vim (possibly efficiently)? Why are you not able to move the cursor? What prevents you from changing `pick` to your desired text?

Comment: I'm asking how to use a very specific part of the vim workflow: The immediate launch of vim when performing a git rebase -i <sha>. I have explained what happens in my particular circumstance and instance and I'm asking if anyone else sees this. If anyone else does see this, do they know how to fix it as I do happen to consider it a problem. Given that vim is the default I don't think that using a different editor is a good solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entering insert mode automatically when editing git commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22366322/1630171)?

Comment: "perhaps random letters entered" Is it possible that the "random letter" must be `i`, `a`, or something else that enters insert mode? (You may know Vim well, but this isn't clear from your question.)

Comment: "do they know how to fix it" There is nothing to fix, here.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `vim` sessions start out awaiting commands (rather than text to be inserted at the caret).  This is typical behavior across `vi` implementations.

If you position the caret using the arrow keys or mouse (as opposed to the traditional `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` commands) then you might find that making `vim` start in insert mode works for you.  You can do this in several ways.  One way would be to change the editor command, by doing this:

```
git config --global core.editor 'vi +star'
```

Of course you'll still have to exit the "insert" mode when you're done, in order to then enter the "save and exit" commands.  (You exit "insert" mode by hitting the `esc` key.)

That said, you may find that it's more convenient to let `vim` start in the default mode, because then you can do things like: position the caret on the `pick` that you want to change; type `c` `w` (the "change word" command); type `squash` (or whatever you want to change the `pick` to); hit the `esc` key to get back out of insert mode. Hit `ZZ` to save and close vim.

(Basically, if you invest the time to really learn how to work with `vi`-type editors, then the default mode will start making more sense; and if you don't want to invest that time, you might want to just switch away from using `vim`.)

Answer (score 31):

I've been through what you're describing and it can be really confusing! I'm hoping this helps, but please reply via comment if anything is unclear and I'll be happy to respond or update my answer :)

In Vim, you start out in `normal mode`.

#### Ready to edit

From there, you can access `insert mode` by pressing `i` and can edit the text as you'd normally expect. When done editing text, press `esc` to return to `normal mode`

#### Save changes

In `normal mode`, type `:wq` and press `Enter` to 'Write' and 'Quit' out of Vim.

#### Horrible Mistake! Need to exit without changes!

To avoid applying your changes in Vim, you'd normally use `:q!` (quit without saving, forced) in `normal mode`, but that won't work for interactive rebasing in the way you'd expect. Instead, you must delete all lines from the text before using `:wq` or `:q!`. An easy way to delete all lines at once in `normal mode` would be to follow the answer selected from [This Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161821/how-can-i-delete-all-lines-in-a-file-using-vi)

#### I want to Squash or Fixup so many lines...

Vim is an amazing text editor and allows you to do so many things! One of my favorites in the context of interactive rebasing is text replacement: in `normal mode`, type `:%s/pick/fixup/g` and all instances of "pick" will be replaced with "fixup". You can then enter `insert mode` to make minor changes to the first commit (change to edit, pick, reword, etc) and any other commit lines as needed.

Comment: nitpick: "command mode" is often called normal mode. This helps clear up a distinction with command-line mode. See `:h vim-modes` for more

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks for mentioning this!

Comment: Would just add that you use ctrl+c to get out of insert mode